# Visual Studio 2015 RC: Emulator for Android : The installer failed. (Code: 1603)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Professional RC, I get the following error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android : The installer failed.
> Fatal error during installation. Error code: 1603

I am not finding anything related for error code 1603. It appears to be a generic error. Any ideas?

I'm running on Windows 10 Technical Preview. [The Visual Studio System Requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#VSP_RC) state that **Windows Emulators**, not Android, require a Hyper-V compatible processor. (my Core 2 does not support that) I don't have Java installed. Is Java required for the VS Android emulator?

**UPDATE:**

As the comments and answers suggest, the Android Emulator appears to require Hyper-V.

A November 12, 2014 MSDN Blog post titled, ["Introducing Visual Studio’s Emulator for Android"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx), under the section, "A peek under the covers" states:

> If you are interested in how we built the Visual Studio Emulator for Android, the short answer is that we reused the work of others. Conceptually, an emulator consists of 4 pieces:
>
> 3. *A virtualization technology* that XDE needs to load the image before it can RDP to it. Windows has a great virtualization technology *called Hyper-V* and that *is what we used*.

(Emphasis added)

XDE is the Windows Phone Emulator Shell that they reused for the Android Emulator.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on Windows 8.1 and  have Java, so that is probably not the issue.

Comment: Are you running AMD or Intel processor?

Comment: An older Intel Core 2 Duo

Comment: My older AMD E2 has the same issue, and oddly, some of the features I installed are missing.

Comment: Actually mine is an Intel Core 2 vPro, slightly newer than the Core 2 Duo, but not new enough to support Hyper-V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are that you have either not enabled Hyper-V or your machine does not allow Hyper-V due to hardware limitations

Comment: I generally agree with this answer. However, do you (or anyone) know for sure that the Android emulator requires Hyper-V? As soon as I can confirm, I will mark this correct.

Comment: There are endless resources in the net for doing that. Here is one of them https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/03/10/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-8-1/

Answer (score 2):

It was the same issue for me. Enabling Hyper-V support in Windows components solved the problem. (`Win+R` -> `"OptionalFeatures.exe"`)
However, in my case, I also had to enable virtualization support in bios.

I found this article helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Good solution, although in my case with limited hardware, I had to move to a different PC.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I actually had Hyper-V already enabled, and still had the error. But after running the VS installer again, it now succeeded.