# do I need windows 8.1 pro to develop with apache cordova

Tags: cordova, windows-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I have a windows 8 and trying to install Vs 2015 with apache cordova, but I am getting error when it tries to install android emulator.

Do I need windows 8.1 pro to develop for apache cordova?

## Edit 1

This is the error that I am getting:

[image: Error message]

The log is as follow:

```
[05A0:3964][2015-06-17T15:52:28]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: 1603
[2A34:2B74][2015-06-17T15:52:59]e000: Error 0x80048646: Process returned error: 0x80048646
[2A34:2B74][2015-06-17T15:52:59]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to execute EXE package.
[05A0:3964][2015-06-17T15:52:59]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[05A0:3964][2015-06-17T15:52:59]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 409517056  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 69135360
[05A0:3964][2015-06-17T15:52:59]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageComplete for secondary installer
[05A0:3964][2015-06-17T15:52:59]i000: MUX:  Disconnecting secondary installer pipe
[05A0:3964][2015-06-17T15:52:59]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80048646 Msi Messages:Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: 1603 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[05A0:3964][2015-06-17T15:52:59]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147187130 (0x80048646), Error Message=Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android : The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: 1603, Result Detail=, Vital=False, Package Action=Install, Package Id=VSSecondaryInstaller_box
```

as I searched and found this:

[Visual Studio 2015 RC: Emulator for Android : The installer failed. (Code: 1603)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089892/visual-studio-2015-rc-emulator-for-android-the-installer-failed-code-1603)

which says that Android exmulator needs Hyper V, but Hyper V is not avaliable on Windows 8.1.

but based on this document: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx

windows 8.1 pro has Hyper V and in my system, I can not see any option to turn it on.

Am I wrong? or the documents are not right?

I am developing on a Dell inspiron 7000 which has a Intel i7-4510 processor with 16GRam.

Comment: I highly doubt it... the only major diff between 'pro' and 'home' versions of windows is the ability to join a domain.

Answer (score 0):

[**Information about Using VS2015 to develop Android app**]

You can install VS 2015 RC on win7, win8 and win10 to develop Apache Cordova app for android platform.

The only requirement on OS that newer than win8 is to build windows 8+ store app and windows phone 8+ app. Check [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054(v=vs.140).aspx), you will find the required OS for using visual studio tools for apache cordova. Check [another doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771545(v=vs.140).aspx) to find out what OS is required to build the app. Learn from [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757059(v=vs.140).aspx) to see if you missed something for android emulator.

[**For Android emulator installation issue**]

So I believe the android emulator installation issue is not related to the OS requirement. See if you can manually install the Android SDK by following the instruction in [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551%20(v=vs.140).aspx#ThirdParty).

Please do share the screenshot or error message to ensure others can understand the exact problem.

[**Update 1**]

Yes. You do need windows 8 Pro edition or higher. One thing I want to highlight is Android Emulator(from Android SDK) is not Visual Studio Emulator for Andriod(only available to VS).

But to be honest, it is not a must to debug and test android app. There are many options available(like ripple).

I suggest you carefully read the docs I mentioned above.

If you have win8 Pro or higher, to enable hyper-v, in control panel-> Programs and Features ->Turn Windows feature on or off ->check the Hyper-V checkbox.

You may find the checkbox is gray and cannot be checked. Generally, that means you didn't enable vitualization in BIOS or the CPU doesn't support SLAT. Move your mouse to the checkbox may give you some specific information. For a very detailed checklist, refer to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff626524.aspx) which has the same requirement for visual studio emulator for Android.

If the Hyper-V is available to you, run repair on VS to get it installed.